# How to take screenshots programmatically in a ReactJS android app?

Tags: android, reactjs

I'm trying to build an android app that allows -

1. Automatically scroll page by page.
2. Take screenshot after each scroll (and ideally merge all screenshots into one image, if possible) and save the resulting image(s) in an album.

For example - the user opens a very long webpage in the browser, then triggers the app which screenshots the entire webpage automatically by scrolling down and taking screenshots until it reaches the bottom.

There seem to be many libraries to do the screenshot part for React Native but I can't seem to find any for ReactJS. Is it even possible with ReactJS or do I need to learn some other android specific technology to make it happen? I'm a ReactJS and mobile app dev newbie, so I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: is it a PWA? I am guessing it's not a native app since you are mentioning react and not react-native

Comment: @JonasPraem Yes, it's a regular ReactJS page compiled into an apk using Cordova.

Comment: When doing pwa's you are limited to the normal browser restrictions. Imagine visiting a web page and the page starts screenshotting your device in the background. Maybe you can do something with the view port, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, your Android app is just a webview rendering the React app.
If this is the case, you cannot do anything at React layer. you have to code the logic at native layer (in the native android application).

Comment: Thank you. Can it be done in React Native instead? I suppose that would compile into a native android app?

Comment: Sure. you said yourself that you found libraries for React Native to do that :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package to take screenshot from any pages
"use-react-screenshot"

but this package have some problems. it works by react hooks
or in take screenshot, svg codes not exist in image